monitor osb Rest services deployed on weblogic?
currently I am working to manage a weblogic server cluster consist of admin server and a cluster of managed servers that host OSB services,
I need to automate the process to get statistics of the deployed services like (ServiceName ,Total request, Success request,    Failure request,    AvgResTime)
I want to write a bash script, the Idea is that I can not find the info,
need help for any end point that I can reach to provide the information, or file the contains these ifno
is there any management endpoint that I could use to retrieve statistics about my rest services...your advice would be Priceless.
